# Pointer Copy to Out of Scope c++

Tags: c++, pointers, vector, scope

Today i went back and investigated an error i got in an old project. It's not exactly an error, rather, i don't know how to do what i need to do. Don't really want to go into the details of the project as it is old and buggy and inefficient and more importantly irrelevant. So i coded a new sample code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <time.h>
#include <random>
#include <string>

class myDoc;

class myElement
{
    int myInt;
    std::string myString;
    myElement * nextElement;
    //a pointer to the element that comes immediately after this one
public:
    myElement(int x, std::string y) : myInt(x), myString(y){};
    friend myDoc;
};//an element type

class myDoc
{
    std::vector<myElement> elements;
public:
    void load();
    ~myDoc()
    {
        //I believe i should delete the dynamic objects here.
    }
};// a document class that has bunch of myElement class type objects as members

void myDoc::load()
{
    srand(time(0));
    myElement * curElement;
    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
    {
        int randInt = rand() % 100;
        std::string textInt =  std::to_string(randInt);
        curElement = new myElement(randInt,textInt);
        //create a new element with a random int and its string form

        if (i!=0)
        {
            elements[i-1].nextElement = curElement;
            //assign the pointer to the new element to nextElement for the previous element 
            //!!!!!!!!!!!! this is the part that where i try to create a copy of the pointer
            //that goes out of scope, but they get destroyed as soon as the stack goes out of scope
        }

        elements.push_back(*curElement);// this works completely fine
    }
}

int main()
{
    myDoc newDoc;
    newDoc.load();
    // here in newDoc, non of the elements will have a valid pointer as their nextElement
    return 0;
}
```

Basic rundown: we have a document type that consists of a vector of element type we define. And in this example we load 20 random dynamically allocated new elements to the document.
My questions/problems:

1. When the `void myElement::load()` function ends, the pointer and/or the copies of it goes out of scope and get deleted. How do i keep a copy that stays(not quite static, is it?) at least until the object it points to is deleted?
2. The objects in the `elements` vector, are they the original dynamically allocated objects or are they just a copy?
3. I allocate memory with `new`, how/when should i `delete` them?

Here is a picture i painted to explain 1st problem(not very accurate for the specific example but the problem is the same), and thank you for your time.
[image: Here is a picture i made to visualize my main problem.]

Comment: Please post [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) - so much better than a picture of something or other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Note: I assumed you want a vector of `myElement` objects where each one points to the element next to it. It is unclear if you want the objects in `elements` to point to copies of them, anyway it should be pretty easy to modify the code to achieve the latter*

This is what happens in your code:

```
void myDoc::load()
{
   ..
   curElement = new myElement(n,m); // Create a new element on the heap

   ...
   // If this is not the first element we inserted, have the pointer for the
   // previous element point to the heap element 
   elements[i-1].nextElement = curElement;

   // Insert a COPY of the heap element (not the one you stored the pointer to)
   // into the vector (those are new heap elements copied from curElement)
   elements.push_back(*curElement);// this works completely fine
}
```

so nothing gets deleted when `myDoc::load()` goes out of scope, but you have **memory leaks** and **errors** since the pointers aren't pointing to the elements in the `elements` vector but in the first heap elements you allocated.

That also answers your second question: they're copies.

In order to free your memory automatically, have no leaks and point to the right elements you might do something like

```
class myElement
{
  int a;
  std::string b;
  myElement *nextElement = nullptr;
  //a pointer to the element that comes immediately after this one
public:
  myElement(int x, std::string y) : a(x), b(y){};
  friend myDoc;
};//an element type

class myDoc
{
  std::vector<std::unique_ptr<myElement>> elements;
public:
  void load();
  ~myDoc()
  {}
};// a document class that has bunch of myElement class type objects as members

void myDoc::load()
{
  srand((unsigned int)time(0));
  for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
  {
    int n = rand() % 100;
    std::string m = std::to_string(n);
    //create a new element with a random int and its string form
    elements.emplace_back(std::make_unique<myElement>(n, m));

    if (i != 0)
    {
      //assign the pointer to the new element to nextElement for the previous element 
      elements[i - 1]->nextElement = elements[i].get();
    }
  }
}
```

<kbd>[Live Example](http://ideone.com/uC74X3)</kbd>

No need to `delete` anything in the destructor since the smart pointers will be automatically destroyed (and memory freed) when the `myDoc` element gets out of scope. I believe this might be what you wanted to do since the elements are owned by the `myDoc` class anyway.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it was really helpful. Thank you for the subtle corrections as well. One small thing, at the time, this was an homework project and i wasn't allowed to use the smart pointers. Do you think a solution without them is possible/worthy of investigation?

Comment: @user3402183 sure, you can obviously allocate memory yourself and manage the deallocation in the destructor. You could either create a `std::vector<myElement>` and have the elements point to other elements in the vector (C++11 offers in-place construction) or just go with a `std::vector<myElement*>` and manage all allocations (aside from the pointers contained in the vector) yourself

Comment: Thanks a lot, i understand it better now.